# Как установить время больше трех минут для ожидающего таймера?

Tags: c++, windows, время

Взял рабочий демонстрационный [исходник](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687008(v=vs.85).aspx) ожидающего таймера от microsoft, но стоит установить в нем время больше трех минут как он перестает правильно работать. То есть таймер срабатывает моментально и без задержки. В чем может быть причина?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    //liDueTime.QuadPart = -100000000LL; // оригинал
    liDueTime.QuadPart = -(10000000 * 300); // устанавливаем на 5 минут

    // Create an unnamed waitable timer.
    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
    if (NULL == hTimer)
    {
        printf("CreateWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for 10 seconds...\n");

    // Set a timer to wait for 10 seconds.
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        printf("SetWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    // Wait for the timer.

    if (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    else printf("Timer was signaled.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чему, по-вашему, равно `10000000 * 300`? Думаете, `3000000000`? А вот и нет, оно в `int` не помещается, так что будет выполнена обрезка...

Словом, укажите явно, что это - `long long`:

```
liDueTime.QuadPart = -(10000000ll * 300ll);
```

Кстати, компилятор же должен был выдать предупреждение! Вы его видели?

Comment: ну если честно то я догадывался об этом, просто положился на компилятор от microsoft думал он то знает свою систему. а я уже взялся читать про формат FILETIME. прям помогли. огромное спасибо за помощь. нет компилятор мне ничего не сказал.

Comment: Включите в компиляторе предупреждения уровнем повыше, а если вы начинающий - еще и "трактовать предупреждения как ошибки". Если используете Visual C++ - то рекомендую ключи `/W4 /WX`

Comment: я в курсе варнингов. студией не пользовался года два просто припекло программу c winapi написать. Я к opensource привык.

Comment: Посмотрел - Open Watcom, например, при `-w=3` тоже сообщает о проблеме. Других под рукой нет :)

Comment: я обычно не доверяю компилятору при преобразовании. но тут же и ide и os от microsoft и я подумал ну разве эта связка не поймет что нужен тип побольше раз в левой части выражения INT64. Глупо как то получается. Из большого сделать маленькое что бы потом опять сделать большое... Зачем нужен такой преобразователь.